# Cannot rbind two data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have two data frames with same column names:

```
setdiff(colnames(qqj_3),colnames(qqb_2))
>>character(0)
```

I checked so that colnames are the same vice versa:

```
> setdiff(colnames(qqb_2),colnames(qqj_3))
character(0)
```

But I can't seem to bind the two correctly:

```
bene_final<-rbind(qqb_2[,order(names(qqb_2))],qqj_3[,order(names(qqj_3))])
```

When I do this only one row is appended (where has more rows should be appended), and when I do below I get an error:

```
> bene_final<-rbind(qqb_2,qqj_3)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

I thought `rbind` wasn't working because the names are not the same, so order should work, but the only one row is appended which I do't understand.

Comment: It only says that alll the column names in the first dataset is matchig with the second and not viceversa.  Check the reverse i.e. `setdiff(colnames(qqj_2),colnames(qqb_3))` as well.  It would be easier with `library(dplyr); bind_rows(qqb_2, qqj_3)`

Comment: @akrun Vice versa works as well: > setdiff(colnames(qqb_2),colnames(qqj_3))
character(0)

Comment: Try with `bind_rows`

Comment: @akrun bind_rows  increased the number of columns by double instead of matching on the same colnames, so I don't understand. setdff() definitely returned none, so the names should match, but rbind results show that probably the column names are not the same?

Comment: Yeah, okay, without a small reproducible example, it is difficult

Comment: @akrun Can I send it to you privately?

Comment: As @RyanD mentioned, you can create a small example with `dput` and edit in your post

Comment: @akrun I'm having trouble because both data sets have 46 colnames, but I'll try to post one

Comment: Please use a `small` reproducible example

Comment: @akrun I need to post the 46 colnames, since I don't know what the problem is. If I subset, I don't get error with rbind.

Comment: @RyanD I added the dput output in the question.

Comment: @akrun I added the dput output

Answer (score 0):

You're re-ordering both sets of columns, when you only need to re-order one set.  Try this:

```
bene_final<-rbind(  qqb_2[,names(qqj_3)],   qqj_3)
```

Comment: I still get > bene_final<-rbind(qqb_2[,names(qqj_3)],   qqj_3)
Error in `[.data.frame`(qqb_2, , names(qqj_3)) : 
  undefined columns selected